# How to insert two tables in a single query using oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

Here I want to insert data in two tables,

**1. COMPONENT_MASTER**

**2. COMPONENT_TO_ACTION**

For this I wrote two queries to insert.But there is a problem with two queries.

**Queries are:**

```
INSERT INTO COMPONENT_MASTER(COMPONENT_ID,ROW_ID,COMPONENT_IDENTIFICATION,COMPONENT_NAME,COMPONENT_TYPE,COMPONENT_STATE,FECHA_DE_CREACION,REVISION)
SELECT MAX(COMPONENT_ID) + 1,?,?,?,?,?,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,? FROM COMPONENT_MASTER
```

**2nd**

```
insert into COMPONENT_TO_ACTION (ORDER_NUMBER,ACTION_ID,COMPONENT_ID,FECHA_DE_CREACION,GRABADO_POR,STATUS,REVISION) 
select max(ORDER_NUMBER) +1,?,?,current_timestamp,?,?,? from COMPONENT_TO_ACTION.
```

Both queries need to insert execute at a time. So both need to insert with same component_id.

Can I write a single Query to insert in two tables.

Comment: @juergend [Yes you can](http://allthingsoracle.com/multi-table-insert-statements-in-oracle/)

Comment: Problem gets solved if you assign Select MAX(COMPONENT_ID) + 1 FROM COMPONENT_MASTER to a variable and do two seperate inserts.

Comment: @ShivaGoudA why are you using `max(<column_name>) +1` to generate new ids? This is bad practice since it does not work well with concurrent sessions (two or more sessions could end up trying to insert the same id, which you presumably do not want). Instead, you should be using sequences.

Comment: Why do you need to do this, are transactions what you are really looking for? Interesting article from @Boneist if you really do want just a single statement.

Comment: @Srikanth A, this is not good, when more then one session at the same time is inserting they select the same value

Answer (score 1):

regarding to your question multi table insert syntax look like:

```
INSERT ALL
into COMPONENT_MASTER(COMPONENT_ID,ROW_ID,COMPONENT_IDENTIFICATION,COMPONENT_NAME,COMPONENT_TYPE,COMPONENT_STATE,FECHA_DE_CREACION,REVISION)
              values (COMPONENT_ID,ROW_ID,COMPONENT_IDENTIFICATION,COMPONENT_NAME,COMPONENT_TYPE,COMPONENT_STATE,FECHA_DE_CREACION,REVISION)
into COMPONENT_TO_ACTION (ORDER_NUMBER,ACTION_ID,COMPONENT_ID,FECHA_DE_CREACION,GRABADO_POR,STATUS,REVISION) 
                  values (ORDER_NUMBER,ACTION_ID,COMPONENT_ID,FECHA_DE_CREACION,GRABADO_POR,STATUS,REVISION)
SELECT (select MAX(COMPONENT_ID) + 1 from COMPONENT_MASTER) as COMPONENT_ID,
       (select max(ORDER_NUMBER) + 1 from COMPONENT_TO_ACTION) as ORDER_NUMBER,
       ? as ACTION_ID,
       ? as GRABADO_POR,
       ? as STATUS
       ? as ROW_ID,
       ? as COMPONENT_IDENTIFICATION,
       ? as COMPONENT_NAME,
       ? as COMPONENT_TYPE,
       ? as COMPONENT_STATE,
       CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as FECHA_DE_CREACION,
       ? as REVISION 
  FROM DUAL;
```

but as guys advise you not to use `select max(...) + 1`.  Oracle has special object to create unique consequent identifiers is sequence. And you cant use sequence in subquery with multitable insert, but you may add it into `values(...)` clause and use it with nextval and curval. Tom Kyte [said that you may rely](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:6915127515933) on insert order .  Please change query to use it and in result you should get something like that:

```
-- for example I create two sequence 
CREATE SEQUENCE COMPONENT_MASTER_seq
START WITH     100000
INCREMENT BY   1
NOCACHE
NOCYCLE;

CREATE SEQUENCE COMPONENT_TO_ACTION_seq
START WITH     100000
INCREMENT BY   1
NOCACHE
NOCYCLE;


 INSERT ALL
into COMPONENT_MASTER(COMPONENT_ID,ROW_ID,COMPONENT_IDENTIFICATION,COMPONENT_NAME,COMPONENT_TYPE,COMPONENT_STATE,FECHA_DE_CREACION,REVISION)
              values (-- /*COMPONENT_ID*/
                       COMPONENT_MASTER_seq.nextval,ROW_ID,COMPONENT_IDENTIFICATION,COMPONENT_NAME,COMPONENT_TYPE,COMPONENT_STATE,FECHA_DE_CREACION,REVISION)
into COMPONENT_TO_ACTION (ORDER_NUMBER,ACTION_ID,COMPONENT_ID,FECHA_DE_CREACION,GRABADO_POR,STATUS,REVISION) 
                  values (--/*ORDER_NUMBER*/ 
                          COMPONENT_TO_ACTION_seq.nextval  ,ACTION_ID,
                          --/*COMPONENT_ID*/
                          COMPONENT_MASTER_seq.curval,FECHA_DE_CREACION,GRABADO_POR,STATUS,REVISION)
SELECT --COMPONENT_MASTER_seq.nextval as COMPONENT_ID, -- Oracle prohibit to use sequence with multi table insert
       --COMPONENT_TO_ACTION_seq.nextval as ORDER_NUMBER, -- Oracle prohibit to use sequence with multi table insert
       ? as ACTION_ID,
       ? as GRABADO_POR,
       ? as STATUS
       ? as ROW_ID,
       ? as COMPONENT_IDENTIFICATION,
       ? as COMPONENT_NAME,
       ? as COMPONENT_TYPE,
       ? as COMPONENT_STATE,
       CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as FECHA_DE_CREACION,
       ? as REVISION 
  FROM DUAL;
```

Comment: what  is got from dual ???  shouldn't the values expected to be fetched from COMPONENT_MASTER and COMPONENT_TO_ACTION as per the question

Comment: ? - is not a standart oracle variable, but it standard template to execute query from different application(java, perl etc) and I make a conclusion that query to be executed from apps . And we see than he get from COMPONENT_MASTER and COMPONENT_TO_ACTION only max value of `id`. As you see I add it into subquery. And I think all is correct

Comment: Right, but in the user's question - the select is from COMPONENT_MASTER and COMPONENT_TO_ACTION inthe inserts. Question should be reframed by @Shiva then.

Comment: @SrikanthA Yes, the selects are from the COMPONENT_MASTER and COMPONENT_TO_ACTION, but they both select the max value plus some constants. This means that they are each returning a single row (because there is no group by clause - you don't need to include constants in the group by, only columns (or expressions involving columns)), so Michael's answer is correct.

Comment: @MichaelPiankov the only problem I can see with your solution is whether component_id is involved in a foreign key between component_master and component_to_action. This is because you can't guarantee the order in which the insert all statement will choose to insert into the tables, so if it attempts to insert into the child table before the parent table, you'll get a parent key not found error. This can be mitigated by making the foreign key constraint deferred, but that can lead to other issues if you forget the constraint is deferred...

Comment: Thank you @Boneist. To be honest problem is deeper. I add to my post